# Is it possible with GAS to automatically send emails when a data validation cell is changed without triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Essentially I have a template of a sheet that is copied and filled out by others to make a request, and then their copy is passed between multiple people for approval based on its status, which is represented by a list of items. I'm trying to add a script to the sheet so that when the value in the status cell is changed, it automatically emails the necessary people to notify them of the status change.

The only way I've found to do this so far is to have an onEdit trigger manually added that checks whether the edited range matches the cell's range, and if so, send the email with the new value held in the cell. Ideally, I would be able to incorporate this into the built-in onEdit(e) simple trigger, but I believe that one of the restrictions included with the simple triggers is that they can't be used to send emails, as it would not send the emails until I added the manual trigger.

My problem is that when other people make a copy of the template, the manually added trigger is lost, so the onEdit function no longer properly sends the email. I was hoping that I could set up this trigger in onOpen(e), but it turns out that creating triggers is also a restricted operation for the simple triggers.

I'm trying to find the easiest way to retain the ability to email when the status is changed. I know I could also just make a button next to the status cell, but my boss is really pushing for it to be automatic to changing the status. Thanks!

Comment: You could use a time driven trigger which could poll for the changes and send emails periodically.  You can install these programmatically  if you wish.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how I would ensure that the time trigger would carry over to the copies made of the template? I've done a bit of programmatically installing triggers but in order to ensure that each copy would get the trigger made I would have to (I believe) create the trigger in onOpen(e), which isn't allowed. Is there another way to ensure that a trigger is created for the copies?

Comment: I don't think you'd have to create a trigger for each sheet.  Presumably there's a way to identify the sheets for open requests and the polling routine would simply look at the information on those sheets and perform the appropriate actions.  It's like having a secretary come in say every ten minutes and check the sheets of active request and perform the appropriate actions.

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified, it's the entire spreadsheet that's copied, not sheets within a spreadsheet

Comment: Publish the script as a web app?